# Get all contacts from iOS device and put them in table view?

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

Hello every one i want to retrive all contacts from iOS device and put the results in table view like the address book

Comment: What's your issue? The TableView? Retrieving the contacts? What have you tried? What have you searched?

Comment: first issue is retrieving contacts .. i didn't find any good resource !!

Answer (score 2):

Start with the [Address Book Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744) and the [Address Book Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/AddressBook_iPhoneOS_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007212)

Comment: Thanks man but they are for objective-c ... is there any thing for swift ??

Comment: All the class references are for both ObjC and Swift.